# A query that runs by itself in Amazon Athena fails to run when I add CREATE TABLE temp_table_name AS on top of it due to a GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

When I run the query (I have reduced the column names and airport codes in the query to reduce your scrolling time) below in Amazon Athena it runs and I get no problems or error messages:

```
SELECT
 "loc id", "runway id", "icao id", "length", "width", "surface type condition", "edge light intensity"
FROM
  "runway_db_athena"."runway"
WHERE
  "loc id" IN ('09J','14A','18A','1V6','22S','2I0','2R4');
```

However, whenever I then try to store this result as a temporary session table so I can perform joins on it with other queries and only have to download the results of those joins using this:

```
CREATE TABLE dash_runs_table AS
SELECT
     "loc id", "runway id", "icao id", "length", "width", "surface type condition", "edge light intensity"
    FROM
      "runway_db_athena"."runway"
    WHERE
      "loc id" IN ('09J','14A','18A','1V6','22S','2I0','2R4');
```

I end up with this:

```
GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: field ended by ';': expected ';' but got 'id' at line 1: optional binary loc id. You may need to manually clean the data at location 's3://realagnifuegos3bucket/Athena-output/create%20dash_runs_table/2023/04/16/tables/230fe35a-e3fc-4b4c-aa46-b6c88efbd8f3' before retrying. Athena will not delete data in your account.
This query ran against the "runway_db_athena" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support  with Query Id: 230fe35a-e3fc-4b4c-aa46-b6c88efbd8f3
```

I have absolutely no idea what's going on there^^, I am still quite new to AWS. So, I went back and changed that first , after "loc id" to a ; just to see what would happen and  this is the Error Message I got back this:

```
Only one sql statement is allowed. Got: CREATE TABLE dash_runs_table AS SELECT "loc id"; "runway id", "icao id",...
```

That^ is exactly what I was expecting to get, but not what I was hoping to get because that means I REALLY don't understand the error message! How is it expecting a semicolon, but then it complains when I give it one?

Comment: It probably doesn't like the idea of creating a column with a name that contains space. Try `CREATE ... SELECT "loc id" as loc_id, "runway id" as runway_id, ...` etc.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I hear you there big time, but I am very worried if I do that, it will create me a new table, but it will be empty!

Comment: What's the harm in trying? You can then `DROP` the table and try something else. Alternatively, you could go into the Glue Data Catalog and rename the columns on the source table (depending on how you have brought in the data).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I agree with that philosophy, so I went back and added underscores between all the fields with spaces with underscores, but it gave me a *SYNTAX_ERROR: line 19:8: Column 'loc_id' cannot be resolved. You may need to manually clean the data*, so I can't change their names I guess. 
Went back to the Glue Data Catalogue and it does allow me to change the datatypes of each field, but not the names unfortunately.

Comment: You'll notice that I suggested referring to the field names _including a space_, but then adding an 'AS' alias to a column name _without_ a space: `CREATE ... SELECT "loc id" as loc_id, "runway id" as runway_id, ...` This will select from the existing `"loc id"` column, but when creating the new table the column will be called `loc_id`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein NO WAY, that worked, and I know that trick too! I was just thinking it was more of an Athena related problem + pulling an all nighter. Feel free to drop the answer and I'll validate it for ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that Amazon Athena is being confused by the space after `loc` in `"loc id"`.

Since it works fine with the `SELECT`, but has problems with `CREATE TABLE AS`, it is likely unhappy with the request to create a table column that has a space in its name.

Try renaming the columns by using an alias:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dash_runs_table AS
SELECT
     "loc id" as loc_id,
     "runway id" as runway_id,
     "icao id" as icao_id,
     "length",
     "width", 
     "surface type condition" as surface_type_condition,
     "edge light intensity" as edge_light_intensity
    FROM
      "runway_db_athena"."runway"
    WHERE
      "loc id" IN ('09J','14A','18A','1V6','22S','2I0','2R4');
```